# Typescript: type of subclasses of an abstract generic class

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-class

I have a Base generic class:

```js
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  abstract itemArray: Array<T>;

  static getName(): string {
    throw new Error(`BaseClass - 'getName' was not overridden!`);
  }

  internalLogic() {}
}
```

and inheritors:

```js
type Item1 = {
  name: string
}
class Child1 extends BaseClass<Item1> {
  itemArray: Array<Item1> = [];
  static getName(): string {
    return "Child1";
  }
}


type Item2 = {
  name: number
}
class Child2 extends BaseClass<Item2> {
  itemArray: Array<Item2> = [];
  static getName(): string {
    return "Child2";
  }
}
```

Now I want to have to define an object with the inheritors as its values:

```js
type IChildrenObj = {
  [key: string]: InstanceType<typeof BaseClass>;
};

/* 
The following error is received: Type 'typeof BaseClass' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type. ts(2344)
*/

const Children: IChildrenObj = {
  C1: Child1,
  C2: Child2,
}
```

Lastly, I want to be able to use statics methods of the children, and also be able to create instances of them:

```js
const child: typeof BaseClass = Children.C1;
/*
received the following error: Property 'prototype' is missing in type '{ getName: () => string; }' but required in type 'typeof BaseClass'. ts(2741)
*/

console.log(child.getName());
const childInstance: BaseClass = new child();
/*
The following 2 errors are received:
(1) Generic type 'BaseClass<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). ts(2314)
(2) Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. ts(2511)
Generic type 'BaseClass<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). ts(2314)
*/
```

Comment: Please share Offer class/type

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry, I forgot to change this. I've re-edited the question. Thx for noticing

Comment: Do you want values to be instances of BaseClass or classes?

Comment: @captain-yossarian If you are referring to `IChildrenObj`, then I want the subclasses to be its values. I'll use it later as a reference to them, and be able to use their static methods and create instances out of them

Comment: If you want class constructors to be values, then you don't want `InstanceType`. The type `IChildrenObj` is not going to be useful the way you want; instead it seems you just want to constrain `Children` to something that has subclass constructors in it, in which case you'd be better off with a constrained helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq8VkN).  The same with annotating `child1` with `typeof BaseClass` (inappropriate) or `childInstance` as `BaseClass` (not valid type).  Can you elaborate on why you need these types at all? Why not just use type inference as in the linked code?

Comment: @jcalz - Hey man, thx for your help and the linked code! You've solved the first error! About the rest of the 3 errors in the last code block: I cannot use type inference because I don't know the value that will be used. 'm interested just in the type itself for further use. The code I've mentioned is just an example to show the errors I'm getting when using such types.

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpfull for you https://catchts.com/oop-style

Comment: I've added a usage example at the bottom of the code, which is similar to what I'm doing in my software: [link](https://shorturl.at/mxI89). My goal here is to understand what type should I write in order to avoid errors.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - this is one impressive article, and I saw that it was written by `jcalz`, which means I'm in good hands here. However, I couldn't understand how this helps in solving my problem, as I'm not trying to do mixin here.

Comment: @A-S I think @captain-yossarian wrote that article, but credited me with some piece of code in it. Anyway, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w26Lzw) work for you?  Essentially `BaseClass<any>` is as close to "some `BaseClass<T>` for some type `T` I don't know and don't want to specify" as you can easily get. Maybe if there's ever some support added for [existentially quantified generics](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) you can do better, but for now I'd say just use `BaseClass<any>` and move on.  If that works I can write up an answer. If not, let me know what issues remain.

Comment: I have tried several approaches and it seems that the easier way is to get rid of BaseClass generic argument.

Comment: A-S just believe me, if @jcalz says that BaseClass<any> is good solution , it is very low chance that you will get the better one. I mean VERY low.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, there were lots of code to alter. It works - you guys are fabulous! There was only one thing I couldn't solve, in the bottom of the following code: [link](https://shorturl.at/rwTXY), I couldn't avoid using `any` in the following code (it's better to view it in the link above): `const anotherCopy: {[offerId: string]: any} = {}; // Can the 'any' be replaced with something???
Object.keys(Children).forEach(offerId => {
  anotherCopy[offerId] = Children[offerId as keyof typeof Children];
});`

Comment: Please provide link to playground with example, it will be much readable

Comment: I did, but there was a problem with the link, here's another try: [link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzx4N). Thx for all of your help!

Comment: shorturl.at/abqK6
I just like `reduce` mor than mutating

Comment: Perfect man, thx! So to sum it up I think the answer should say that there's no way to represent such type, without hardcoding the type of the subclasses in it (i.e. typeof Child1 | typeof Child2). That's why you keep changing the code so it will get the type from the value without mentioning the type itself. Did I get it right? If yes - then please write an answer for me to approve

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, the type

```
type IChildrenObj = {
  [key: string]: InstanceType<typeof BaseClass>; // instances?
};
```

is not appropriate to describe your `Children` object.  `Children` stores *class constructors* while `InstanceType<typeof BaseClass>`, even if it worked for abstract classes (which, as you noted, it doesn't), would be talking about *class instances*.  It would be closer to write

```
type IChildrenObj = {
  [key: string]: typeof BaseClass; // more like constructors
};
```

But that is also not what `Children` stores:

```
const Children: IChildrenObj = {
  C1: Child1, // error!
  // Type 'typeof Child1' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseClass'.
  // Construct signature return types 'Child1' and 'BaseClass<T>' are incompatible.
  C2: Child2, // error!
  // Type 'typeof Child2' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseClass'.
  // Construct signature return types 'Child2' and 'BaseClass<T>' are incompatible.
}
```

The type `typeof BaseClass` has an abstract construct signature that looks something like `new <T>() => BaseClass<T>`; the callers (or more usefully, the subclasses that extend `BaseClass`) can choose anything they want for `T`, and `BaseClass` must be able to handle that.  But the types `typeof Child1` and `typeof Child2` are not able to produce `BaseClass<T>` for any `T` that the caller of `new Child1()` or the extender `class Grandchild2 extends Child2` wants;  `Child1` can only construct a `BaseClass<Item1>` and `Child2` can only construct a `BaseClass<Item2>`.

So currently `IChildrenObj` says it holds constructors that can each produce a `BaseClass<T>` for *every* possible type `T`. Really what you'd like is for `IChildrenObj` to say it holds constructors that can each produce a `BaseClass<T>` for *some* possible type `T`.  That difference between "every" and "some" has to do with the difference between how the type parameter `T` is [quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)); TypeScript (and most other languages with generics) only directly supports "every", or *universal* quantification.  Unfortunately there is no direct support for "some", or *existential* quantification.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#14446](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) for the open feature request.

There are ways to accurately *encode* existential types in TypeScript, but these are probably a little too annoying to use unless you really care about type safety. (But I can elaborate if this is needed)

Instead, my suggestion here is probably to value productivity over full type safety and just use [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to represent the `T` you don't care about.

---

So, here's one way to define `IChildrenObj`:

```
type SubclassOfBaseClass =
  (new () => BaseClass<any>) & // a concrete constructor of BaseClass<any>
  { [K in keyof typeof BaseClass]: typeof BaseClass[K] } // the statics without the abstract ctor

/* type SubclassOfBaseClass = (new () => BaseClass<any>) & {
    prototype: BaseClass<any>;
    getName: () => string;
} */

type IChildrenObj = {
  [key: string]: SubclassofBaseClass
}
```

The type `SubclassOfBaseClass` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of: a concrete [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that produces `BaseClass<any>` instances; and a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which grabs all the static members from `typeof BaseClass` without also grabbing the offending abstract construct signature.

Let's make sure it works:

```
const Children: IChildrenObj = {
  C1: Child1,
  C2: Child2,
} // okay

const nums = Object.values(Children)
  .map(ctor => new ctor().itemArray.length); // number[]
console.log(nums); // [0, 0]

const names = Object.values(Children)
  .map(ctor => ctor.getName()) // string[]
console.log(names); // ["Child1", "Child2"]
```

Looks good.

---

The caveat here is that, while `IChildrenObj` will work, it's too fuzzy of a type to keep track of things you might care about, such as the particular key/value pairs of `Children`, and especially the weird "anything goes" behavior of [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and the `any` in `BaseClass<any>`:

```
// index signatures pretend every key exists:
try {
  new Children.C4Explosives() // compiles okay, but
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); //  RUNTIME: Children.C4Explosives is not a constructor
}

// BaseClass<any> means you no longer care about what T is:
new Children.C1().itemArray.push("Hey, this isn't an Item1") // no error anywhere
```

So my suggestion in cases like this is to only make sure that `Children` is assignable to `IChildrenObj` without actually annotating it as such.  For example, you can use a helper function:

```
const asChildrenObj = <T extends IChildrenObj>(t: T) => t;

const Children = asChildrenObj({
  C1: Child1,
  C2: Child2,
}); // okay
```

Now `Children` can still be used anywhere you need an `IChildrenObj`, but it still remembers all of the specific key/value mappings, and thus emits errors when you do bad things:

```
new Children.C4Explosives() // compiler error!
//Property 'C4Explosives' does not exist on type '{ C1: typeof Child1; C2: typeof Child2; }'

new Children.C1().itemArray.push("Hey, this isn't an Item1") // compiler error!
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item1'
```

You can still use `IChildrenObj` if you need to:

```
const anotherCopy: IChildrenObj = {};
(Object.keys(Children) as Array<keyof typeof Children>)
  .forEach(k => anotherCopy[k] = Children[k]);
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=91&ssc=19&pln=90&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQB4AVAPgQG8BYAKAQVEhngQEsIcBbAQShgCeALgR9BpMgG46dBpGAQ2sBAHMcEAHLAuOABQBKEczYA7FVVkMEEABZQA9gHcEJnM4Ci-e1F0ADbGD4hBgAtAgA5Gqa2jjhCI5oLvaI9gBuOPxsACZZOCYAhL760vQIAL4ypaacUCbAyAAy9ipKBlTldBW0dBACAA44CACSnFwAjAgAvBaldTpG0KYqnXQoaBh4NmzIWRM4AB6cJlkYAUHrRCPcYxQ0VaNiwMKi-E+XozdTCADaALolcggCiUqnUWh0BgWUCWMysCCg6gArrUEAAiTbbXaogEdWhdHr9QZXLgAJi+dwYcxwIhMiK4IAyK1oa3QCAxOzJByOJywuAIF2JJNulg43Eez3F724Qq+fxx8kUyii4L0hgQxjMsKsCIgyJMaPZWRJ2MsXXxtF6A2G2CyhoRJgA8iAAFbkyzfADWOGeGpUvxElpw9gAZrzAvz0J0Sqt7CZILzbVsdvaREMbXa8k7XdMKWyxiJDWMADQIAD0pYQGQcUHylnLCBIhIigZDbKTuzibAwJmSjHQbBUdRAyEGEHs1ib4RbobOEbA4QAdHWK3hY8xEawwAO6rqEfCkSjAxhwoW4sBjhFZ8EJGe96ZYPYuH1gcOcEvSngSQX2ySS-Wq94talPWjZWlOhKtoaJKdt2vbrNuoAjtY46Bs2EEznywSLsubJrtAG6IFug4KMigw6nqE4DMeUFnhe4RXhc5C3oM96Ps+iivu+5r-vsXZHIo9SViYD5ZEsJZjuO549gISwElaADKj74O2XxEAASmQuiwCAIgSFpY5QDSbgIG0kwUAxxDkPoUwUGp1lmQgaklA+caIGgik6IaqkkEWmnwN4RnOKZ5mYYxZBqh5ymYjZSAgDF2n6d4xRyUSkUZo6Lrkj8Xo+osZj+ggaUqWUzl4YVSnpamRWYvaWZuh++Z9tVOy6IW+hFpYn4iO5FXtq1P76EyLnxmASkaHSGDTFmODwAuqT1IiOBgLozVZPa+gLlwwB9LolijZ5KkOftUUtf5UAxa4zhnQYC6irwrwCAuI5mLYg20G9KWFYiIAsmADrBhZk2WLol0mfZIXhte54COFCAAGRlhWwBILGsA6oMw34WdCCtoDRDQ2QliUD8ADS7D6jlrbTmG5zoAV1OA98JO-OUiPWDYgwKkoGCOBwNj2IiiC2IMTDQHAiBnZUpYAFSUYM8nfb9-2A18IPGcFNNzvjJgw9ZCO5gwfQOGOgYiHjBM4gwyoxCIGu+iUZQINLpaVKhQzpXVObujlUJLAVCs-cEyuhZGeKVJjbY1XkqYe5lXsNd+mLFp1X6RxyHVh90zJlbSXCTQg02zfNyCLct6VvQwm3bYl50OaD10bXd4pPXkKivZIbO5wyUB-DGcb2COT3NCDE3FGz3wAAwlhPvzhznMT54XEBzQtS39VHJgVwgVc7djDlnQu1sQvo1n1r6vfZ-3g-IMPVJgGP9bfOi7ZjKiJbP5ixqz1n0ACFqoPpQXHgAALO4fYfQb5bnSMtU+FYHxPm2EtHGHonglhAILToSAFCwBsCZKs1lczDQHm+G+KhdD4I7vWQAvBuAFKdxyABVDQJAhgAFl3CJ2THkIBoDwGQLYNA9gsE3Io1clAAi3gmR0AAe2e0QCxg3Sbg9BcfRERgBsLoVEAAJb04ktgYC7CYKcjB9TElfrApIlYvDnWho4DmCJKhSIXs+WAgxMDqBqDMSwEc0Cx2zAgUglZDh5B5O7GRmYXSaQgCIEg4NrA4gjulL4PiwkZWdLoA2eYOG7AznCLqacjQ5PKA-Cs9gUECEqAwX+WpKTGUASAsBED7BQLXuY+BfREHnQAjWSwDBywAAUHADCgL0CI9TeFNP4UtOIWR7BIJ7IgA4fEcb6lQuEYmeBGrU0LB3PJWyfwdzKOEU0WCIA4LwfwAhuJLDSI3nIhRDwlEqLURo7RAhdFdkEYYtyJiPiolaWxDpljqxAV6RWPgKg6R5BSKGVZvoYJJDcv2Yir5kIIGfDAHQHiqaTlMUcrODBvHzLsauPozxQkb09lQEqwMl4LhymXFJ1lEiSkpjC9C+T7ThR6dvYM3h3BwHUR6GK55kjEvsKSz0LNpjpUlclLOZQgA)